# Complex Calculation - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on calculating a larger set of data with a number of joins and the end result is a calculation across two tables. My current script looks like the following:

```
USE db1
Go

SELECT 
    customer, tb1.custid  
FROM 
    [dbo].[tb1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[tb2] ON tb1.custid = tb2.custid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[tb3] ON tb2.custnumber = tb3.custnumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[tb4] ON tb2.custid = tb4.custid
WHERE 
    tb1.custclass = 'non-person' 
    AND tb4.zip IN ('11111', '11112') 
GO
```

As you can see, it's not the cleanest, but it's working for gathering initial information. The reasoning for the number of joins is due to an incredibly odd table structure I did not create and the fact that the numerical data I need is only stored in tb3.

What I'm now trying to do is calculate the sum of 3 fields from tb3 that are all set as numeric fields and do an AND/OR comparison against a 4th field (also numeric). I know I can SUM them together, but I'm hoping for some input on three things:

1. Where to place that SUM calculation in the query?
2. Where to place and how to do the comparison of the SUM total against the 4th field?
3. Is it possible to return the higher of the two values to a TOTAL column in the initial SELECT?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  Start with a simple sum.  What options do you have as far as where to put it?

Comment: It is not that uncommon to have data spread over several tables. But be carefull with sums and the like when joining several tables: in case you have three matching records in t4 you get your t3 data three-fold. Also: Are you sure you need outer joins? The last one doesn't even work, as you compare a t4 value in the WHERE clause without considering that that value would be null in case of an outer-joined record. In case you do need an outer join, you may want to move that criteria to the ON clause instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where to place that SUM calculation in the query?

If you want it output, you probably want to just add it to the `SELECT`

```
SELECT 
    customer, tb1.custid  
    (tb3.col1 + tb3.col2 + tb3.col3) as Sum
FROM 
   ...
```

> Where to place and how to do the comparison of the SUM total against the 4th field?

You probably want to do this with a `CASE` statement, and this also answers your last question

> Is it possible to return the higher of the two values to a TOTAL column in the initial SELECT?

```
SELECT 
    customer, tb1.custid  
    CASE WHEN (tb3.col1 + tb3.col2 + tb3.col3) > tb3.col4
         THEN (tb3.col1 + tb3.col2 + tb3.col3)
         ELSE tb3.col4
    END as Total
FROM 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to calculate the sum as a nested query:

```
SELECT (field1 + field2 + field3) AS fields_sum FROM tb3 (...)
```

Then in your main query you could do something like:

```
SELECT customer, tb1.custid, (CASE WHEN fields_sum > fourth_field THEN fields_sum ELSE fourth_field END) AS TOTAL (...)
```

Comment: From the question `the sum of 3 fields from tb3` - your first part sums one field across the entire table.

Comment: Edited; I wasn't paying enough attention there.  Thanks.  Regardless, your solution is probably a bit more elegant.